# Using google play developer api but didn't get app all reviews

Tags: php, laravel

I have try this api for app all reviews but didn't get app's all reviews

[image]

But I get only two reviews

[image]

I have tried this steps

1 . create a Oauth client ID  and secret in google cloud console

2 . Enable google play developer api and add scopes

3 . I have get my app test users login and get access token

[image: code]

[image: access token image]

4 . I get only two reviews

[image: output]